# How can I make Cloudbees Jenkins Enterprise use a community Jenkins instance as a Slave?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

This isn't necessarily an ideal production setup, but I need to create a slave on a community edition install of Jenkins with a Cloudbees Jenkins Enterprise master. The two seem to use different ways of configuring slaves so are they compatible?

Two Linux servers:

1. Jenkins Enterprise - Master
2. OSS Jenkins - Slave

I need to spin off a job on an OSS Jenkins machine (2) with the artifacts generated from a job on the Enterprise machine (1)

The reason I need to do this is because I don't have full admin access to the Enterprise server so I can't for instance open a port for selenium, so I want to delegate that task to an OSS machine to run unit tests where I have more control.

Is there compatibility between the way Open Source and Enterprise Jenkins configure master/slave relationships, and how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your terminology is very misleading. A Jenkins “slave” is a build agent, not a standalone server. What you are apparently talking about is two *masters*: one CJE, one OSS.

That said, what you apparently want to do is cause a build on one master to trigger a build on another master, passing along an artifact. Now for CJP customers there are (at least) three ways to do that:

1. Have both masters be in a single CJOC cluster, and use the remote trigger functionality. Easy and recommended, but not an option if one of your masters is not licensed (since all masters in a CJOC cluster must have a license).
2. Have the upstream build start the downstream build using Jenkins REST or the CLI `build` command. Requires the upstream to have an authentication token valid on downstream which has Job/Build permission; or you can use a per-job build token. Have the downstream build use REST to download the artifact from upstream (similarly may require downstream to have an authentication token valid upstream with the Build/Artifacts permission). Works with OSS masters.
3. Use the Secure Copy plugin, with or without any CJOC cluster, to replace the second part of #2 without needing downstream to have any authentication on upstream. Still requires upstream to have authentication to build downstream (or a job build token). But requires both upstream and downstream to be licensed for CJP.

Comment: Licensing aside, we have required licenses, I'm looking to add a controlled slave on a community Jenkins to a CJE master.

Comment: Do you mean that the community Jenkins slave needs a licensed JCE plugin?

Comment: There is no such thing as a “community Jenkins slave”. You can run an OSS Jenkins _master_. And controlled slaves are a JCE feature.

Comment: By the way you should probably just use the [support site](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/).

Comment: I updated the question with more detail about what I need to do. I am a mere cog, not the one in our organization who handles the licensing or relationship with Cloudbees. I understand if you are an employee of Cloudbees and would prefer not to answer here, I'm hoping someone else will.

Comment: Just noting your options in case you were unaware. Probably this “answer” should really have been a comment on the ambiguity of the question, but it seems too late to change now.

Comment: I think technically when submitting an answer it should address the question(s) in this case: are OSS and Enterprise compatible, how to configure master/slave between them. I believe the "add a comment" link is a better choice for asking for clarification of a question.

Comment: OK clearly I had some concepts mixed up. Thank you for the update.